# Javascript - EventListener not working in external js-file

Tags: javascript, inline, event-listener

I am trying to remove the onClick tags in my html and add an EventListener to my external js-file instead, but can't seem to get it to work.

The following lines work:

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="test">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka" id="klick" onclick="skriv()">
```

When removing onclick and adding the following to my javascript, it does not :

```
document.getElementById("klick").addEventListener("click", skriv);

function skriv() {

    var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
    alert("Hello" + " " + input);

}
```

Entire html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hello.css">
    <title>
        Multimedia
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
        <div>
            <form>
                <p>Skriv ditt namn:</p><br>
                <input type="text" name="text" id="test">
                <input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka" id="klick">
            </form>
            <p class="lol">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do"`enter code here`
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

you are missing window.onload, checkout [demo with separate script.js file](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw0RZDebkO7xi8Z5cJVa?p=preview)

```
window.onload = function () {
  var buttonElement = document.getElementById("klick");
  var inputElement = document.getElementById('test');


  if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', skriv);
  }

  function skriv() {
    var input = inputElement.value;
    alert("Hello " + input);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks Vilas! Good solution.I used it in a php form to call an external js file. The event listeners would not work until I did the above.

Answer (score 2):

Place your `<script>` tag right before your closing `</body>` tag.
Or use another way to detect your DOM is ready.

```html
<body>


  <div>
    <form>
      <p>Skriv ditt namn:</p><br>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="test">
      <input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka" id="klick">
    </form>
    <p class="lol">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do"`enter code here`
    </p>
  </div>



  <script> // Or external JS URL
    document.getElementById("klick").addEventListener("click", skriv);

    function skriv() {

      var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
      alert("Hello" + " " + input);

    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because when the script is loaded, there are no elements to be found on which it can bind the event.

Solutions.

- Move your script to the bottom of the body tag.
- or you can Use Delegate

  ```
     document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
         for (var target=e.target; target && target!=this; target=target.parentNode) {
         // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
             if (target.matches(<selector>)) {
                 handler.call(target, e);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }, false);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose just to add the following right before the closing  tag:

```
<script> window.onload=startListen(); </script>
```

On the first line of your .js-file, you add `function startListen(){ * }`

You replace the * with all your eventListeners you want.