# Javascript keydown doesn't work in separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
  alert("You hit the enter key.");
  } else {
  alert("Oh no you didn't.");
  }
}
```

if i paste it in the template it works fine, but if i put it in external file, it doesnt work. Although all other javascript in the external file works fine.I have also tried with this code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

but the same story. What am i doint wrong?

Comment: You're probably trying to attach the event listener before the element exists in the DOM. Put the `<script>` element referencing your external JS file just before the `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341761/javascript-eventlistener-not-working-in-external-js-file) covers your problem.

Shortly: it matters which moment you add eventListener to the document. 
It should be applied on windows.onload

Comment: If another answer answers the question then it's a duplicate question and should be closed. If you're requesting more information required to answer the question then you're out of luck until you have enough rep to comment :)